# updating numbers pandas python but also keep all the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two dataframes:

DF

| Contact | phone1 | phone2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 061234 |  |
| 2 |  | 0612345 |

DF1

| Contact | phone1 | phone2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 061236 | 12344 |
| 2 | 1222 | 0612347 |

I am using the update() function to update the two dataframes

```
df.set_index('Contact', inplace=True)
df.update(df1.set_index('Contact'))
df.reset_index()  # to recover the initial structure
```

Result

| Contact | phone1 | phone2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 061236 | 12344 |
| 2 | 1222 | 0612347 |

Is it possible to get the other numbers too?
Something like this

| Contact | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 061236 | 12344 | 061234 |
| 2 | 1222 | 0612347 | 0612345 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) method to do it :

```py
df = pd.merge(df,
              df1,
              how='outer',
              left_on=['Contact'],
              right_on=['Contact'],
              suffixes=['_df1',
                        '_df2'])
```

And then rename the columns as you wish using :

```py
df.columns = ['contact', 'phone1', 'phone2', 'phone3']
```